# Recursive solution to this combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics

How does one calculate a recursive solution to this combinatorial question?

> A machine can give out coins of 1, 2 or 5 dollars. If the machine has to return n dollars, in how many ways can it return such an amount?

I thought about this.
Let us assume we have an array of size n.
Each index is equal 1.
In how many ways can we put blocks of 1, 2 or 5 in the first 5 indexes?

There are 4 ways:

1. 1 item of 5 blocks,
2. 5 items of 1 blocks,
3. 2 items of 2 blocks, 1 item of 1 blocks
4. 3 items of 1 blocks, 1 item of 2 blocks

In sum, there are 4 ways.
Then all we have is a problem of $f(n-5)$

My final answer is:
$ f(n) = 4 \cdot f(n-5) $
when
$f(0) = 1, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 2, f(4) = 3, f(5) = 4$

But that is obviously wrong. Because $f(6) \; \text{should be} = 6$ while in my equation it turns out $4$.

Comment: You seem to believe that a solution for $n$ dollars must contain a sub-solution for $n-5$ dollars. This is not true, one could make $6$ dollars (or any even amount) using pieces of $2$ only. Even more seriously, even if there is a sub-solution for $n-5$, it need not be unique. In fact there is very little special about $5$, you seem to be on a wrong track.

Comment: And that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for Pólya's paper ["On picture writing"](http://www.computing-wisdom.com/jstor/picture-writing.pdf) (AMM 63(10):689-697 (1956)), it shows how to solve the problem for changing a dollar in cents, dimes, nickels, quarters and half dollars. The same technique is applicable here. Graham, Knuth, Patashnik in "Concrete Mathematics" show how to derive a closed formula for Pólya's problem.

Comment: Not what I was looking for though... my intention was to purely simply solve it with recurrence

Comment: In that paper, it is solved by using generating functions. I must do it in a recursive way, to get to a recursive equation, and not with generating functions.